# Openscap CIS RHEL6 Profile unavailible?

Tags: openscap

I'm running Open-SCAP Workbench 1.2.0 on RHEL8.6 installed via dnf, rpm: openscap-1.3.6-3.el8.x86_64.

While choosing a profile after loading the 'RHEL 6' content (an ssg-rhel6-xccdf.xml file located in /usr/share/xml/scap/ssg/), I was unable to find a CIS RHEL6 Profile similarly to how as seen with RHEL 7 and RHEL 8 contents, profiles named 'CIS Red Hat Enterprise Linux <7/8> Benchmark for Level 1 Server'

I know that there is a CIS RHEL6 benchmark available via:  [CIS Benchmark Downloads](https://downloads.cisecurity.org/#/)

Does anyone know if there's a RHEL 6 CIS profile available in openscap workbench or another xccdf.xml file that is required?
Or is there a similar profile available in this current xccdf that you would recommend to me, (a lay person with little security knowledge)? I've been using CIS Red Hat Enterprise Linux <7 & 8> Benchmark for Level 1 - Server if that is any helpful gauge.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the CIS for RHEL 6 hasn't been implemented in a form of SCAP profile. Unfortunately, the upstream community has stopped all development for RHEL 6 because RHEL 6 is basically end of life, and they are focusing on RHEL 8 and 9.

Comment: That makes sense. RHEL6 is going away sooner than later. Thanks for your answer.